# Unable to disable intermediate/backlinks coming from amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, google-search-console

I am hosting a website on an EC2 instance and monitoring the website through the Google Webmaster tool. There I am getting 15000 backlinks from amazon. So, is amazon making my website pages which are on the instance as public ?

Practically, the tool should not know that I am hosting my website on AWS and should not display the links for my pages. But still it is showing all the links for my webpages which are on AWS.

I do not want that the google webmaster tool should display amazon links for my website. How can I stop it ?

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/. It will let you remove your URLs from Google once you've verified ownership of the site.